# Does binary search in any case work with physical numbers themselves? Excluding 0

Tags: binary-search

If there is a list in numerical order, (1 - 10) will binary search work with it? If the answer is no, can I have an explanation why it won't?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Binary search works with any array that is sorted.

Take searching for 3 as an example; assume we have a list of numbers from 1 to 10.

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

First, we divide it in two.

```
1 2 3 4 5      6 7 8 9 10
```

Since 3 is less than 6, we go with the first half.

```
1 2 3      4 5
```

Since 3 is less than 4, we go with the first half again.

```
1 2    3
```

Since 3 is equal to 3, we go with the second half.
And we have found 3.

Comment: Just to clarify you used the Highest index + Lowest Index / 2 formula to find 3? 10 and 1 in the first iteration?

Comment: @wild_o Yes, that is what I did. I'll revise my answer to make it clearer.